# In how many percents does the yield increase if I water the trees every day?

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax, interrogatives

I want to ask about the increase in the percentage of something, but I am not sure what is the way to ask it in an interrogative way.

Can I say:

> **In how many percents** does the yield increase if I water the trees every day?

Comment: Please look up the word *percent* in a dictionary. If you visit Lexico or Collins you'll see a number of examples of how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as 'a percent' - the word means 'in every hundred'.

You used the word *percentage* in your first paragraph. You can say *By what percentage does the yield increase?*